# Simple SQL Update statement not being transactional

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, transactional

Using SQL 2016.

I have an Orders table:

```
 OrderID int identity
 NumberOfItems int
```

And an Items table:

```
ItemId int identity
OrderId int
DateUpdated datetime
```

An order is created and an OrderId is assigned via identity.  Then I have to assign the "Freshest" "NumberOfItems" Items to it from the Items table. Freshest meaning, they have been updated the most recently, according to the DateUpdated date.  Items are "assigned" by updating their OrderId to the OrderId in question.

I have this SQL to assign the items in a transactional fashion (@OrderID and @NumberOfItems are input parameters):

```
    UPDATE Items
        SET OrderId = @OrderId
        WHERE ItemId IN
               (SELECT TOP(@NumberOfItems) ItemId FROM Items
                WHERE OrderId IS NULL -- not already assigned
                ORDER BY DateStatusUpdated DESC -- freshest first
               )
```

Should be good right?  This should transactionally assign Items to Orders and no matter how frequently or concurrently this statement is run against the server, the same Item should never be re-assigned to another order once it's already been assigned.  This should be guaranteed by pretty much any relational database ever implemented due to the necessary transactional nature of the single UPDATE statement used.

Well, it had been working that way for several tens of millions of orders.  Then, last night, two orders came in about 50ms apart (which isn't particularly close for this application), and one Item was assigned to OrderN and then the same item re-assigned to OrderN+1!!

What could have possibly caused this to happen?

Comment: What is the isolation level on DB?

Comment: Read Committed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there are two calls to the Item table.
Try this refactored query which does the same with single call:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
;WITH LimitedUpdate AS (
    SELECT TOP(@NumberOfItems) i.OrderId
    FROM Items i WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE i.OrderId IS NULL
    ORDER BY i.DateStatusUpdated DESC
)
UPDATE LimitedUpdate SET OrderId = @OrderId
;
```

Keep original query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
UPDATE Items WITH (UPDLOCK)
SET OrderId = @OrderId
WHERE ItemId IN
        (SELECT TOP(@NumberOfItems) ItemId FROM Items WITH (UPDLOCK)
        WHERE OrderId IS NULL -- not already assigned
        ORDER BY DateStatusUpdated DESC -- freshest first
        )
;
```

Comment: It's all within the UPDATE statement though and there are no dirty reads going on.  The SQL I gave should be executed transactionally.  I've used this similar technique for decades with absolutely no issues.

Comment: I fail to see how that would be any different.  Oh you edited and added UPDLOCK :-)

Comment: If I just want to modify my existing SQL and not use the WITH clause, would I put the UPDLOCK after the UPDATE ITEMS or after the SELECT or both?

Comment: As Vladimir correctly said it will work only in Serializable Isolation level

Comment: I've tested few things - maybe it's overkill, but WITH(XLOCK,HOLDLOCK) will definitely help - but it is exclusive lock, so please be aware.

Answer (score 0):

`READ COMMITTED` isolation level doesn't provide the guarantee that you want, as you have already discovered yourself the hard way.

In short, engine executes `SELECT` part first, without locking the table/rows.
It locks the table/rows only when performing the `UPDATE` phase, but this step happens later.

So, two queries running simultaneously may read the same rows and then try to `UPDATE`.

No matter how you try to rewrite the query there will always be two separate phases - `SELECT`, then `UPDATE`. You can see them in the execution plan.

The "easy fix" is to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level for the whole query, but it may be overkill and some hint (such as `UPDLOCK` may be enough).

I don't have much experience with these hints, though.

Comment: Hmmm... It's all within a single UPDATE statement though.  I don't think two concurrently-executing queries should be able to update the same rows, since the UPDATE will issue WRITE LOCK and prevent reading uncommitted data of any other SELECT.  Had there been something fundamentally wrong with this statement I think I would have seen a problem occur more than once in several hundred million transactions.

Comment: That's the point. Yes, the `UPDATE` operator in the plan would lock the rows/table, but this lock is placed right before the update, not before the whole query starts. The first phase of the query is `SELECT` and during this phase there are no locks in place yet. This is why `UPDLOCK` hint or equivalent is needed in your case. You need to tell the engine explicitly that you want to place the lock right at the start, during the reading phase and hold that lock till the end of the statement/transaction. Under the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level the locks are held for shorted period.

Comment: "single statement" doesn't mean that everything that is done within this statement is atomic from the concurrency point of view. The statement has several steps, several physical operators and these steps are executed in parallel when several queries run at the same time.

Comment: So adding a simple "with(updlock)" after the "UPDATE Items" should resolve this?

Comment: @Harold, I don't have much experience with these hints. I'd set isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`, but maybe it is the same as the hint. You'd better ask another question. Show two variants of your query, with hint and with `SERIALIZABLE`. Explain the concurrency issue that you are trying to avoid and ask if their effect would be the same and whether this would provide the guarantee that you need. Ask also, maybe there is a better way to guarantee what you need. Also, dba.stackexchange.com may be a better place for such a question.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help Vladimir.  Have a nice night.